# What is the nature and order of the Surahs in the Quran?

Tags: quran

The Christian Bible is, of course, the work of many authors over many centuries, and is more properly considered a library than a single book. While there is a general order to some of the books (there's "sort of" a chronology, but not really), there is no reason to read them in order.

It is my understanding that the Prophet (PBUH) is considered to have received the entirety of the Qur'an all at once - but is its authorship considered to be all from one person as well?

And how is the Qur’an, then, arranged? My understanding is that the individual Surahs are simply arranged in order of size - is there any other basis?  And, as a result, should one read the individual Surahs separately, or is there a story progression that should be considered when jumping from one Surah to the next?

Comment: See also: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/838/how-was-the-order-of-the-quran-decided

Answer (score 2):

**Briefly speaking, according to the view point of most expounders (interpreters)  (  المفسرین ) or Olama’ (of Quranic sciences):
The arrangement of the verses of each Surah are Toqifi    and in accordance with the order of Nozul  (coming down to the Prophet(s)) and has arranged by Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) himself.**

Even some of them claim the Ijma’ (الاجماع), suck as Syuty that says:

> Ijma’(consensus) and Abundant Nosoos bodes that the arrangement of the
>   verses is Toqifi, and there is no doubt about this.
>
> (Al-Atghan, volume1, page189, N18)
>
> (الاتقان، ج ‏1، ص ‏189، نوع 18)

**Of course, we ought to pay attention that the current arrangement of the holy Quran verses is not the same with the order of its origin. Prophet Muhammad (blessing of Allah be upon him and his family) himself ordered to change the order of verses to make the holy Quran as the current order of it and in fact we can say that it was by order of Allah.**

---

Source:

- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread22051.html)

Answer (score 1):

Quran was revealed to the Prophet (SAWW) both at once and verse by verse during 23 years. Firstly it revealed to the Prophet (SAWW)  during 10 years of his prophet-hood verse by verse and again it was revealed at once.

The current arrange of verses of Quran is different of order of reveal of verses. Prophet himself ordered to change order of verses to make Quran as current order and it was by order of God. By this Change in verses of Quran, Quran became like a shuffled puzzle and more difficult to understand. When Imam Mahdi a.s. (the 12th Imam) come back of Occultation will order to change the sort of verses of Quran as its original revelation order.

In fact current arranged of Quran is by order of God to prophet SAWW.

All the Quran is revealed to Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) by angel Gabriel and the Prophet (SAWW) taught it to his companions and encouraged them to memorize it and thousands of companions of him memorized all the Quran under audit of prophet.

There is no story progression in start to end of Quran. But there are story progression for each story of Quran. Stories of Quran are also distributed in different Surahs.

There is no Jumping needed. Only:

> لَّا يَمَسُّهُ إِلَّا الْمُطَهَّرُ‌ونَ
>
> Which none shall touch but those who are clean.
>   http://tanzil.net/#56:79

Purify your heart of any evil moral and read Quran as a honest and serious truth seeker who is ready to pay any cost for finding truth. even if that cost is leaving wine, losing Job, being mocked by friends and family,... if so God himself opens door of your mind and heart to understand Quran so deeply that most of Muslims do not understand. God inspires the meanings to your heart and mind. Read Quran will deep asking of guidance from God himself.

If you prove to God that you do strive in way of finding truth, then God himself guides you and even if needed sends some of his Wali (close friends) to talk you and guide you without even you know him or he know you previously to you know God correct and can meet God.

> وَالَّذِينَ جَاهَدُوا فِينَا لَنَهْدِيَنَّهُمْ سُبُلَنَا وَإِنَّ
>   اللَّـهَ لَمَعَ الْمُحْسِنِينَ
>
> And those who strive in Our (cause),- We will certainly guide them to
>   our Paths: For verily Allah is with those who do right.
>   http://tanzil.net/#29:69

It is recommended to while reading Quran wash yourself and be clean and hold Quran in your hands with respect and it is better to read Quran when at least for 40 days no wine is drunk. Because God does not accept who drink wine until 40 days. Truth is expensive! And its price is higher than money. Its price accepting truth whenever comes to you at any cost and disobeying evil thinks coming in mind.

---

References and some suggested resources:

[An Introduction to the Glorious Qur'an](http://www.al-islam.org/glorious_quran/) by Bahram Samii

[The Qur'an in Islam](http://www.al-islam.org/quraninislam/index.htm)

[Understanding the Uniqueness of the Qur'an](http://www.al-islam.org/al-tawhid/default.asp?url=unique-quran.htm)

[A Reflection on the Collection of the Holy Qur’an](http://www.al-islam.org/tahrif_quran/)

Comment: As a one-time Baptist, I haven't had any alcohol in 40 years, so I should be good in that regard :)  What I'm looking for, however, is a more dispassionate "how to."  I'm open to Truth, but I'm looking for an entry to read the Quran that doesn't presuppose the end.  My guess is that you were raised Muslim, as I was raised Christian. If I'm going to find truth, I need to be convinced, but I'm sufficently open to go about it in the proper way.  That's why I'm looking for this answer.

Comment: @AffableGeek its very good to hear that. wine was only an example. I do not think any suggested ordering exist for reading surahs of Quran. you can start from first or any surah. they are not arranged by size. I added some resources I hope be useful

Comment: @Ahmadi, by 10 you meant 23? Also as long as I know Shia Muslims agree on the order of verses in each Surah (_the order is in the Prophet's order_), the difference would be the order of Surah's in the book (_now being more or less length-based_), am I wrong? Imam Mahdi A.S. will bring no different book but the same book with all the verses being described with its revelation conditions and hidden glosses of its words and verses!?

Comment: @owari thanks. yes. it was my mistake. there are some verse less but before the greater surah. but approximately can be said arrange is less to more. yes Imam Mahdi S.A. does not change text of Quran. only change the arrange of verses and surah to arrange they were revealed before prophet change the arrange of verses and surah by order of Allah. also you can edit answers when you see errors or want to improve answer.