# Did the Quran exist in it's present order before the death of Prophet (SAW)?

Tags: quran, hadith, prophet-muhammad, ramadan, caliph

I was reading the below Hadith:

> Narrated `Aisha:
>
> Once Fatima came walking and her gait resembled the gait of the
>   Prophet (ﷺ) . The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Welcome, O my daughter!" Then he
>   made her sit on his right or on his left side, and then he told her a
>   secret and she started weeping. I asked her, "Why are you weeping?" He
>   again told her a secret and she started laughing. I said, "I never saw
>   happiness so near to sadness as I saw today." I asked her what the
>   Prophet (ﷺ) had told her. She said, "I would never disclose the secret
>   of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)." When the Prophet (ﷺ) died, I asked her
>   about it. She replied. "**The Prophet (ﷺ) said: 'Every year Gabriel used
>   to revise the Qur'an with me once only, but this year he has done so
>   twice.** I think this portends my death, and you will be the first of my
>   family to follow me.' So I started weeping. Then he said. 'Don't you
>   like to be the chief of all the ladies of Paradise or the chief of the
>   believing women? So I laughed for that."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 3623, 3624](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/129)

The bold sentence highlighted above makes we wonder if the order of the verses was divinely inspired and not put together by Caliph Umar (RA) as claimed by some.

Will it be more appropriate to think that the Sahaba knew the whole Quran by heart as it exists today and Caliph Umar (RA) only put it in a standard book format because he feared it may be lost/corrupted due to the large number of death of Huffaaz in a recent battle?

Comment: I always thought it is part of Aqeedah to believe that the Quran was divinely ordered. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Seems relevant [How was the order of quran decided](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/838/how-was-the-order-of-the-quran-decided)

Comment: @Medi1Saif Jazakallah Khair