# Chronological order of ayahs

Tags: quran, surah, ayah

We know that in Quran the surahs are ordered in a certain way, but the chronological order of the revelation of the surahs is different. (One can see that in [here](https://tanzil.net/docs/revelation_order).)

My questions are:

1. Are ayahs inside a surah ordered according to revelation of them?
2. Surahs have a revelation order. But was it the case that one surah was revealed completely? In other words, were the ayahs revealed randomly and later composed in particular surahs the way scholars saw fit?
3. Did prophet Muhammed (PBUH) approved or had any say about the present composition/structure of the entire book?

Additionally I am interested to know the process of collecting and ordering the ayahs/surahs to the present format.

Comment: If you look to the "related" links on a web-browser (PC) you will find an answer for your second in third question in [How was the order of the Qur'an decided?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/838/how-was-the-order-of-the-quran-decided?rq=1) and this way it is clear that question 1's answer isn't a "yes".

Answer (score 1):

The verses within each surah may not be arranged according to the sequence of their revelation. Sometimes, verses were revealed to be in specific places within a particular surah based on the guidance of the Prophet Muhammad (may Allah bless him and grant him peace), who was receiving guidance from Jibril, peace be upon him, about the location of each verse.

There are surahs that were revealed in their entirety at once, but this does not apply to all surahs. Some surahs consist of verses revealed at different times and situations, and they are collected into one surah.

The Prophet (may Allah bless him and grant him peace) received revelation from Allah s.w.t, and the Prophet taught the Companions the order of the verses and surahs as he was commanded. The current structure of the Qur’an, in terms of the arrangement of the surahs, was established during the reign of the Companions after the death of the Prophet (may Allah bless him and grant him peace), and is believed to reflect the order that was followed in the Prophet’s time.

After the death of the Prophet, the Companions took upon themselves the task of collecting the Qur’an into one Qur’an to ensure its preservation. Othman bin Affan (may Allah be pleased with him), played a prominent role in this process. The Qur’an was compiled based on the main outlines left by the Prophet (may Allah bless him and grant him peace), and each verse was verified with the complicity of the Companions who memorized and wrote it during the reign of the Prophet (may Allah bless him and grant him peace).

Comment: About the naming of the surahs, is there any hadith or sirat reference of naming the surahs? If not, how were they named, I mean who decided that?

Comment: Abd al-Rahman b. Yazid said:
I asked Abu Mas'ud while he was making circumambulation of the Ka'bah (about the recitation of some verses from the Qur'an). He said: **The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: If anyone recited two verses from the last of Surah al-Baqarah** at night, they will be sufficient for him.