# The Quran and the Hadith

Tags: quran, hadith, revelation

What is the relation between the Quran and the hadith? The Quran is the Word of God, but what about the hadith? Are they the interpretations of men or are they also divine revelation?

Also does the question of naskh apply in relation between the Quran and the hadith? Do the hadith then abrogate the Quran?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Hadith and Qur'an?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4254/what-is-the-difference-between-hadith-and-quran)

Comment: Or perhaps [Does the Quran always override the Hadiths?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1983/11593)

Comment: You appear to be asking too many questions here, some of which have already been answered on this site.  I would recommend you take the time to focus your question (see also our help centre page on "[How do I write a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)")

Comment: All the questions lead from the first question about the relationship between the Quran and the Hadith. While there are about five questions they are convergent, and in fact Mujahid answered concisely.

Answer (score 3):

The Hadith is also divine revelation. Allah says:

> وما ينطق عن الهوى إن هو إلا وحي يوحى
>
> And he does not speak out of his own desire, it nothing more then a revelation revealing

سورة النجم

Hassan bin attyah said:

> كان جبريل - عليه السلام - ينزل على النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم - بالسنة
> فيعلمه إياها كـما يعلمه القرآن
>
> Jibreel used to come to the Prophet with the Sunnah and teaches it to
> him just like he teaches him the Quran

***Also does the question of naskh apply in relation between the Quran and the hadith? Do the hadith then abrogate the Quran?***

Yes.

---

[Source](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/134848)

Answer (score 0):

The hadith is what our prophet (SAW) said.In a way it is kinda a divine revelation because the prophet speaks what Allah wants him to tell the people. So Quran is from Allah and hadith is the words of the prophet (SAW).