# Are there any sects of Islam that believe the Qur'an has been changed?

Tags: quran, sects

There are very many questions on here about the [authenticity of the Qur'an](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/639/is-it-possible-that-the-quran-contains-any-errors), how [it hasn't been changed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-do-we-know-that-the-quran-has-never-been-changed), and many good answers. But, like any religion, there are diverse opinions on almost any point. I haven't, however, heard of or been able to find any sect that states the Qur'an has been changed or updated. It seems to be a universal belief that it has not been changed.

Are there any (or were there any in the past), and if so, what reasons do they give for their difference of opinion?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Concerning the authenticity of the quran, there is no sect that doubt it as far as I know, as most sects believe in the Quran and it is stated by God Himself that Quran is preserved. The divergence between sects goes into some interpretations of Quran and mostly beyond the Quran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not among any sect in ahlul-sunnah, all ahlul-sunnah believe quran is in its origonal shape.

And also in shia sects, many sects believe in its authenticity you can read details [here](http://www.shiapen.com/comprehensive/tahreef/shia-scholars-completeness-quran.html), their are few in shia who believe that this version of Quran is not complete(although this view is not accepted by shias in general), and complete version of quran(which some say have 10 more chapters) is with imam gaib, who will bring it when he will like it and they narrate some ridiculous stories about it.

So, in short, almost all muslims believe in Quran's authenticity. There's never been any proof(which could be held strong in court of shariah or any other judiciary) of it being corrupted in any sense.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful and I didn't know that about the incompleteness.